# Draw android:foreground over imageview in XML only

Tags: android, xml, wear-os

I have an `ImageView` that is pulled as @ID which will not respond to `android:foreground` or `android:alpha`

I have tried messing with various XML parameters such as weight, positioning, etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/WatchStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:foreground="@drawable/ring"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="28.0dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="18.0dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28.0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="1.0dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1.0dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/time_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1.0dip"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="13:26"
                android:textColor="#ff88bbff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/timeFontSize"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/graph_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.0dip"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="15.0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:contentDescription="@string/blank" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/top_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="2.0dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2.0dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1.0dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="  "
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:textSize="@dimen/glucoseFontSizeRound" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="1.0dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1.0dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/egv_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="136"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/glucoseFontSizeRound" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/egv_unit_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="-6.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14.0dip"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:text="@string/mgdl"
                android:textColor="#ddddddff"
                android:textSize="@dimen/mgdlFontSizeRound" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/trend_rate_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="4.0dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/blank"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/single_up" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My understanding was that `android:foreground="@drawable/ring"` should draw the ring graphic on top of everything. However, the graph_view `ImageView` is still overlaying it. Similary, including `android:alpha="0.5"` will not render the `ImageView` translucent.

This is the watch face of an android diabetic monitor app, which frankly, is as ugly as it can be. So I'm trying to at least modify the looks within the possibilities, which is only the watch_face_round.xml layout file.

I managed to add a background image, change the layout and some colors, and add the ring surrounding the background image. The result so far is this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JNjyfgoq4EAJPIo05a5rokSWt7JM5-sv/view?usp=sharing

But as you can see, the graph in the center (the above mentioned `ImageView`) overlays it. I have no idea where the graph actually comes from, but I have to assume it's generated by the watch face or actually sent from the phone app that feeds the numbers to the watch face.

I have no access to any of the java files, just the decompiled app.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: WearOS watch faces don't use layouts like you may be used to on Android: the face is drawn directly to a `Canvas` in Java, so most likely the graph here is being drawn after the layout is inflated.

Comment: IOW, there's probably nothing you can do in this layout file to achieve what you're describing. If you've decompiled the app, though, you *should* be able to get at [ugly] Java and tweak that.

Comment: Thank you, while I wasn't able to edit the java itself, since many of the files decompiled with errors, I did find where to edit the .smali file to change colors and alpha. I still can't get the ring to draw over everything, but I was able to make the diagram semi-transparent, which is good enough for now.